# wp_create_user hook

Tags: user-registration, wp-create-user

I'm using **UserUltra Pro** plugin and I need to create a custom post type after user register in the site. *UserUltra* plugin uses `wp_create_user()` which I know is a wrapper for `wp_insert_user()`. Moreover, I know that 'user_register' is the hook called after `wp_insert_user()`.

Beside this, I can't create new custom post type because it seems that `user_register` hook is not called. Is this possible? How can I manage it?

Comment: what are you trying to do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are actually [two actions](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/4.0/wp-includes/user.php#L1595-L1636): One when the [profile is updated](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/4.0/wp-includes/user.php#L1858) and [one when the user is registered](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/4.0/wp-includes/user.php#L1867).

```
# Fires immediately after an existing user is updated.
do_action( 'profile_update', $user_id, $old_user_data );

# Fires immediately after a new user is registered.
do_action( 'user_register', $user_id );
```

So as long as the user login is not empty and the user name does not exist, it should proceed. Take a look at the return clauses:

```
if ( empty( $user_login ) ) {
    return new WP_Error('empty_user_login', __('Cannot create a user with an empty login name.') );
}

if ( ! $update && username_exists( $user_login ) ) {
    return new WP_Error( 'existing_user_login', __( 'Sorry, that username already exists!' ) );
}
```

That means if you ain't get an `WP_Error` object back, it should execute. You can try the numerous filters inside the core function to narrow down where things break if your hook isn't executing. The one running *before* the error returns, is the following:

```
apply_filters( 'pre_user_login', $sanitized_user_login );
```

If this one works, then the plugin simply isn't checking for `is_wp_error()` and ignoring the failing insert call.

```
<?php /** Plugin Name: Test if wp_insert_user() filters work */
add_filter( 'pre_user_login', function( $user )
{
    var_dump( current_filter()." works fine" );
    return $user;
} );
```